# Trying to test if bit 1 of a byte is turned? Bit shifting

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

I have a byte and I want to test if Bit 1 is turned on.

The condition I wrote is: `if(byte & (1 << 0)) return true;`

Confusion: I not understand how to read a byte.

**Is Bit 1 this?** ie. (1 << 0)

```
00000000
       ^
```

**Or this?** (1 << 1)

```
00000000
      ^
```

In other words, do we read a byte from 0 -7 or 1 - 8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit)

Comment: I asking how to semantically read a byte when bit-shifting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In computer science, counting always starts from 0. So the 0th bit is the rightmost one. That's why, in the example in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/141873/7315159), `110 (6) << 1` becomes `1100 (12)`. This also means that shifting by 0 is a null operation (it doesn't do anything).

This also means that for your case, if you want to test the rightmost bit, all you need to do is `byte & 1` - no shifting necessary.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. Just to clarify my understanding. We count a byte from 0 to - 7. The rightmost bit is called bit 0... and if I want to turn on bit 1 - we're semantically talking about bit 2 (if counted from 1 - 8)?

Comment: Yes, you have it correctly, the bits in the byte will be indexed `[7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0]` (e.g. first-bit, index `0`, second-bit index `1`, etc...).

Comment: I see. Also trying to understand last example in your answer: say if I had; if (packet & (1 << 3) shouldn't it be true only if bit-4 (aka bit 3 counted from 0) of packet is set to 1?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Think about bits as a set of blocks on a table, where you can only see the one that's on the right. Anytime you want to see any other blocks, you have to shift them left or right to focus on a different block. So if you start by focussing on the first bit from the right, you have to shift three times to be able to see the fourth bit from the right. However, to avoid confusion when talking to other developers, I recommend you adopt the starting-at-0 terminology, because it's the most well-established and everyone will understand what you mean.